# How to tell GCC to map include directory?

Tags: gcc

I need to compiler source code that contains includes like this:

```
#include <tr1/unordered_map>
```

However my compiler (based on GCC 4.6) does not have the `tr1` directory. I need to somehow tell the compiler to map `<tr1/unordered_map>` to `<unordered_map` without modifying source code of file system?

Comment: What about specifying the include directory and then doing `"unordered_map"`?

Comment: Like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aefe8886f49c8446)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit hacky: Go to the include directory containing `unordered_map` and:

```
ln -s . tr1
```

Comment: Looks like it's the only choice here. Sad, I thought there is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

when you build your code, provide include directory as an argument.

> **-I.** - For current directory as an include directory
>
> **-I tr1** - tr1 as an include directory.
>
> **-I /yourpath/** - To put any directory as include directory

Comment: As far as I understand, the compiler will look for the name "tr1/unordered_map". So despite what directory I add to includes list, it must contain subdirector "tr1" with header "unordered_map". Unfortunately this is the problem, there is not "tr1" directory anywhere. I want to tell the complier to ignore "tr1" and just look for the header itself in all include directories.

Comment: but this should work as what you include will be searched from all the  include directories also. isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but it will search for "tr1/unordered_map.h", not just "unordered_map.h". And since there is not "tr1" it won't find it. Or my assumption is wrong?

Comment: my understanding says, it should look for only unordered_map.h rather than tr1/unordered_map.h, you can give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

Gcc headers `<unordered_map>` and `<tr1/unordered_map>` are different. One requires C++11 support turned on, the other does not. Substituting one for the other may or may not work.

Probably the easiest solution to your problem is to use the `tr1` implementation from Boost.